# Cerberus FTP User cannot download file in subfolder

Tags: permissions, ftp, directory-listing

I am using Cerberus FTP 9.0 and have a user trying to download a file called "file.csv" in a subfolder. They're provisioned as a user with permissions and can download files from a subfolder of the root.

Root: C:\Main\UserFolders\UserName

Folder that works fine: C:\Main\UserFolders\UserName\Data

Folder that says permission denied: C:\Main\UserFolders\UserName\Data\ExtraData

It was my understanding that the permissions set at the Root level trickled down to all subfolders, even subfolders of subfolders. Is this not correct? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Explorer, visit `C:\Main\UserFolders\` , right-click `C:\Main\UserFolders\UserName` & go to `Properties>Security` & also check `Properties>Security>Advanced` looking at given user.

Properties must match those of `C:\Main\UserFolders\UserName\Data\ExtraData` , including `Properties>Security` & `Properties>Security>Advanced` against given user.

**You will most likely see discrepancies. You can rectify those.**

In case there are no discrepancies, you could consider attaching those Properties to your Post and we can Proceed onto other Possible Issues.

[[ When you say "Permissions set at the Root level trickled Down" , that is true for Cerberus Virtual Directory Permissions , but Windows Server Permissions will override that and will throw Permission Issues when user has no Permissions  to access some item. ]]